# Mobile Site editing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, web

Can someone please help me edit the CSS for this website of mine for mobile sites, on the homepage?

Keep in mind that this is done through Wordpress and the theme I am using does NOT allow me to edit the theme CSS itself, however, I am using a plugin that allows me to add my own custom CSS to it. Take a look at this if you don't understand.

[image: take a look at this if you don't understand]

Please help me out. I've been trying to center all of the text in each sections for mobile but nothing is working someone help!

I can add code if needed be, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting this code on your site.  It should fix the "Proven Success" section on mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 667px){

.categories .module-title {
    left:0px !important
}

.categories .module-subtitle.font-serif.home-prod-subtitle {
left:0px !important;
}

.section-overlay-layer .module-subtitle.font-serif.home-prod-subtitle  {
    margin-left:0px !important;
}

.module-subtitle {
    margin-left:0px !important;
}

}
```

Comment: thank you that worked! can you please help me with the other two sections? the section with the girl picture and the one right below it that has a button linking to products?

Comment: @Elizer Wohl can you please help me with the other two sections?